# Linear to log scale

Tags: functions

I need to convert an angle in degrees to a value between 0 and 28000 on a log scale. The angle scale is linear, from 0 to 360 degrees, and the expected output should be the value for that angle from a logarithmic scale from 0 to 28000. I'm working in javascript but can probably convert algorithms from c or similar languages.

I would expect x = 30 to give a result close to 28, x = 120 to give a result something like 280 and x = 240 should produce something like 2800.

Comment: There are problems with taking the log of $0$.  Do you want to take $0$ to $0$?  Then which direction should be logarithmic?  People use it both directions.

Comment: Oh yes, I did notice in my research there were problems with log 0. I don't actually need log 0 since 0 is 0 on both scales. Thanks for your quick response Ross.

Comment: But the log changes infinitely quickly at zero, so just matching them up is not sufficient.  Do you want the $28000$ range to be proportional to the log of the $360$ range or the other way around?

Comment: 1 degree should give me a value near the beginning of the log range and 359 degrees should give me a value very close to 28000. near 0 degrees I should get low numbers. In other words, the slope of the log scale is flat towards the zero end and exponentially steep near the 360/28000 end. Sorry, I'm not a mathematician so my descriptions may not be helpful.

Comment: Your update suggests that at $x = 0$ you are expecting output around $28$, at $x = -120$ you are expecting output around $2.8$, and so on.  With this, the output you expect never reaches zero, no matter how negative $x$ is.  Also, this is not logarithmic; it's exponential: an increment in input produces a multiplication to the output.  For a logarithm, multiplying the input by a constant adds a constant to the output.

Comment: Perhaps it is an exponential scale rather than logarithmic, as I said, I'm not a mathematician. I am not concerned with negative degrees. I would expect 30 degrees to give a result of around 28. I am interested in the values between 0 and 360 degrees mapping (I believe logarithmically) to values between 0 and 28000.

Answer (score 0):

As a line in the sand (i.e., probably not what you're actually thinking of)...

$$  f(x) = \frac{28\,000 \log(x+1)}{\log 361}  \text{.}  $$

We have $f(0) = 0$, $f(360) = 28,000$.  We do not have $f(2x)/f(x) - f(x)$ is constant, essentially because we only let the logarithm go down to zero (so we have necessarily shifted the graph of the logarithm to the left and ignored what has crossed to the left of the $y$-axis).  This is unavoidable if you require the output include $0$.

Comment: Thank you Eric but that formula doesn't seem to give me the answers I'm looking for. I would expect x = 120 to give a result something like 280 and x = 240 should produce something like 2800.

Comment: @PrajnaPranab : You should add that to your Question.  No one is going to guess that out of thin air.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've added that to my question.